# What's an alternative for AS ' ' in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Every time I try to write out

```
SELECT ID, att_id AS 'Attribute ID'
FROM Table
```

it says

> ERROR: syntax error at or near 'Attribute ID'.

How can I use the `AS ' '` function in postgresql?

Comment: I don't know postgresql, but you shouldn't be putting an alias in single quotes (or any kind of quote, ideally)

Comment: `as 'attribute id'` is invalid standard SQL to begin with. Postgres honors the SQL standard, that's why it rejects this. The relevant section of the manual is here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: I would suggest using underscores instead of spaces. Will save you a lot of troubles down the road. And you won't need to use quotes or backticks

Answer (score 3):

You should use double quotes instead of single quote

Comment: Single quotes are for values.  Double quotes are for table and column names.